# Install PIP packages on Dataproc existing cluster

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc, dataproc

Is there a way to use

```
pip install
```

or something like that to install packages on a existing dataproc cluster? Or will I need to re-create and set the packages on PIP_PACKAGES?

Answer (score 0):

There is no automatic way of installing packages on all nodes of an existing cluster. Depending on your use case, you may have to ssh into master and worker machines to install these packages. It will be easier to use initialization actions instead and create a new cluster.

Comment: I just want to add a documentation link https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/python-configuration